# PHP - Fatal error: Class 'Stripe\EphemeralKey' not found?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create an Ephemeral Key for my Stripe Customer, but for some reason, my php backend throws the following error?

> Fatal error: Class 'Stripe\EphemeralKey' not found in
>   /var/www/html/myFile.php on line 21

Any idea why this is happening?

```
     <?php // Create a customer using a Stripe token

  require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

        // If you're using Composer, use Composer's autoload:

        ini_set('display_errors',1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);

        // Be sure to replace this with your actual test API key
        // (switch to the live key later)
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("MYLIVEKEY");

        if (!isset($_POST['api_version']))
        {
           header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
        }

        // Create Stripe Customer
        try {

            $key = \Stripe\EphemeralKey::create(array(
            "customer" => $customerId, // Convert amount in cents to dollar
            "stripe_version" => $_POST['api_version']
                )
            );

           header('Content-Type: application/json');
            exit(json_encode($key));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
        }

        ?>
```

**EDIT:** Composer.json file added below.

**composer.json**

```
{
  "name": "stripe/stripe-php",
  "description": "Stripe PHP Library",
  "keywords": [
    "stripe",
    "payment processing",
    "api"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://stripe.com/",
  "license": "MIT",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Stripe and contributors",
      "homepage": "https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/contributors"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "ext-mbstring": "*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "php-coveralls/php-coveralls": "1.*",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~2.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "Stripe\\" : "lib/" }
  },
  "extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
      "dev-master": "2.0-dev"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello again! Have you tried `\Stripe\Stripe\EphemeralKey` instead of `\Stripe\EphemeralKey` ?

Comment: Tried it, still same error :/ @Jonathan

Comment: @user1597430 require_once('vendor/autoload.php') should take care of this? No?

Comment: Which version of the Stripe library are you using?

Comment: Not sure (I just looked in the readme file and it doesn't say which v it is?) That said, I have another php file with the same structure that calls \Stripe\Charge and that works perfectly with this version? @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Check your composer.json-file to see what version it's set to. `Stripe\Charge` has been available way longer than `Stripe\EphemeralKey`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Oddly, doesn't say the v number in there either. That said, when I go into my stripe-php/lib folder I do see EphemeralKey.php. Should I install the latest stripe-php version just incase?

Comment: If it's there, then it should work (if it is in the vendor folder you're looking). You said that it doesn't say which version it's using in the composer.json file? What does the required-line for Stripe look like?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

Comment: That's how you load the autoloader. My question was about your `composer.json`-file. You should see a line in the `require`-seciton: `"stripe/stripe-php": "what_does_it_say_here?"`. Also, when you checked that the file existed, did you check in the correct `vendor`-folder? You can also search for `stripe/stripe-php` in the `composer.lock`-file to see what version it actually have installed.

Comment: See composer.json file added above! And yes, the vendor folder exists with the autoload file. EphemeralKey.php doesn't exist in the vendor folder, it exists inside stripe-php/lib/ @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Your setup seems very strange. What you should have is _one_ composer.json file in the root of your project. There, you define what dependencies you have (like `stripe/stripe-php`. Then when you run `composer install`, _all_ dependencies will be stored in the `/vendor`-folder, which is the one you should `require '/path/to/your/vendor/autoload.php'.` Update your question to include the file/folder structure of your app (including where the composer.json-file(s) are).

Comment: Wow, you might be a genius. So I just went into vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib, and you are correct, EphemeralKey.php IS MISSING from there... while Charge and others are present. Which, explains my problem :) Stand by... @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Dragged EphemeralKey.php into the mentioned vendor sub-folder. Seems to solve the previous issue, but now I'm thrown the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_USE, expecting T_FUNCTION on line 23 ("customer" => $customerId,). I assume the syntax error is due to the version of php I'm using... @MagnusEriksson

Comment: **No no no**. Don't manually change anything in your vendor folder! If you a composer update, your changes might disappear. Plus, the version of Stripe you're using might not support that class. You should make sure that you use at least version 4.13 of the Stripe-library instead (which is when they added that file). I would recommend to use the latest version, though.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Ha! Ok, I've updated to the latest stripe library. That said, how do I get the vendor folder to update with the missing file? Run composer install again?

Comment: _"I've updated to the latest stripe library"_ - If you did it with Composer, then it should already been added in the vendor folder automatically. That's the whole point of Composer. You define what packages you want and which versions you want. Then you do a `composer update` to get the new versions (which will be stored in the vendor folder automatically). I would recommend looking at some tutorials about Composer.